# Tag editor button and Ctrl+T not opening in CFEclipse Release 2 (4.4.2) in Win 7

Tags: coldfusion, tags, cfeclipse

I cannot get the tag editor to open on a selected tag.

Also it would be great of I could get it to open on right click like Homesite.

I have searched both Luna and Adobe's site and just get sent in circles.

Comment: CFEclipse is not an Adobe product, so there's no point looking there. Perhaps try the CFEclipse website: http://cfeclipse.org/. Possibly also ask on the CFML Slack channel: https://cfml.slack.com/

Comment: Thank you Adam. I do know that CFEclipse is not an Adobe product. I usually do not post here unless I cannot find an answer on Stackoverflow or somewhere else. Especially with software issues.

I am trying to get CFEclipse to function more like Homesite 5.5 which I really like but it was discontinued many years ago so tag definitions are often stale.

Information about CFEclipse and it's big brother CF Builder is virtually non-existent and I was hoping somebody has gone through and solved this issue.